# CouchDB issue regarding data reading from API's

Tags: java, couchdb

I am using CouchDB 2.0.0 version.
I am trying to retrieve data from API's using java code.
The url when hit in the browser works fine, but does not show data in eclipse.
for eg., while using the following url:

```
http://<ip-address>/_node/couchdb@localhost/_stats
```

But I get the following exception while doing so:
java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server

```
 at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:802)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:663)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:799)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:663)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1335)
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late. I've encountered this problem also. The server actually responded with an error because when calling from java you must specify the type of authorization (usually Basic), along with the user info encoded using Base64. It works with the browser and curl, because both adds that request property.

Assuming you are using:

```
http://<ip-address>/_node/couchdb@localhost/_stats
```

Your connection might be configured as followed:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setConnectTimeout(2000); // Two seconds (or any timeout you decide) timeout
// Other user agent can be used. I've also tried curl/7.51.0 as user agent as well
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
if (url.getUserInfo() != null && !"".equals(url.getUserInfo())) {
    // userInfo MUST be Base64 encoded
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeBase64String(url.getUserInfo().getBytes()));
}
connection.setUseCaches(false);
```

Hope this helps.